# async/await stuck forever

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Writing a webapp that uses async/await but got stuck where the line `var r1 = await fetch(url).then((r) => r.text())` appears to be handing forever. My web server listening on port 80 didn't even receive the request.

```
const fetch = require ('fetch-node')
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var savedResolve;

app.listen(8079, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('listening on 8079')
})
app.get('/*', async function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.path)
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    await task()
    res.send('Done')
})


async function task() {
    console.log("starting..")
    var url = "http://localhost/prod/te.php";
    var r1 = await fetch(url).then((r) => r.text())
    console.log(r1)
    return "done"
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

**Update1**

Thanks to suggestion by @deryck, add try and catch around the line of `fetch` call, got the following error instead

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined
    at module.exports (/Users/jsmith/learn/node/node_modules/hooks-node/hooks-node.js:8:11)
    at module.exports (/Users/jsmith/learn/node/node_modules/fetch-node/fetch-node.js:17:1)
    at task (/Users/jsmith/learn/node/te4b.js:22:18)
    at /Users/jsmith/learn/node/te4b.js:13:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jsmith/learn/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/jsmith/learn/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/jsmith/learn/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jsmith/learn/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/jsmith/learn/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/Users/jsmith/learn/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
```

Comment: wrap that line in a `try {} catch (e) {}` and see what error comes up if any.  oh and I don't use fetch much but assuming fetch() returns a promise you don't need `.then(..)` - your result of r1 would be what is inside that `.then((r) ...)`

Comment: Thanks @Deryck,  I tried your suggestion and got the error/stack trace.  Updated the answer accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: one thing you could try is using a different way of getting that data.  there's no reference to `render` in your code here and that stack trace just goes through that module.  try `request-promise-native` - i use that everywhere and love it.  or just native node http.get(URL).

Comment: Based on the shown code you most likely want to use the library [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) and not [`fetch-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-node).

Comment: What are you using fetch-node for ?

Comment: @Deryck I am not sure how "render" get into the picture.   I installed request-promise-native and it works well.  Thanks for that!! Curious why the module fetch-node doesn't work.

Comment: @t-niese  that's a great catch!!  I changed to node-fetch and it works well!

Comment: @t-niese please write it up as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @pktCoder An additional note: if you do not use a async function any further in cobmination with an await or for chaining, then you should add a try catch block in it: An express middelware that uses `async` should look like this: `app.get('/*', async function (req, res, next) { try { /* your code */ } catch( err) { next(err);} });`. Otherwise an unhandled rejection of that promise will result in a crash of the application in future. If you use Promises you might want to switch to koa.

Comment: @t-niese Good point on try/catch. I will check it out Koa. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) and [`fetch-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-node) are two differnt libraries.

And based on the shown code `node-fetch` is the library that should be used.